# Kafka Stream order by based on specific field

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a custom object like below.

```
public class CustomObject{  
    public int source;
    public long value;  
    public long timestamp;
}
```

Values are like below

```
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062731364,31300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.10 Value => -1062729572,31400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062731193,14300,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.7 Value => -1062729401,14400,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.9 Value => -1062731124,28100,1615979127
Key >>>>> 111.10.73.9 Value => -1062729332,28200,1615979127
```

This is the KStream object

```
final KStream<String, CustomObject> source = builder.stream("topic");
source.<???> ???
```

Now, what is the best way to sort the stream object based **on the value field**? Like Java Stream has *.sorted(Comparator.comparing*****).

Output: Filter out the top 3 from the list based on the highest value.

Comment: what is it you want to achieve via sorting? Can you be more clear?

Comment: I wanted to filter Top 3 from the list based on the highest value.